# FOREACH in LINE BOT FLEX

Tags: php, mysql, foreach, chatbot

can anyone help me with this problem?

I had a LINE Messenger BOT, and I want to implement `foreach()` loop to show a list from the database I have. but I struggle with the code. here is what I wrote

```
function indexflex($title,$label,$text){
    $data = $this->Dbs->getdata_kamusengineer()->result();
    foreach ($data as $d) {
        $dariindo=$d->dariindo;
        $bajep=$d->bajep;
        $arraynumber= 0;

        $itemindeks=array (
            'type' => 'box',
            'layout' => 'vertical',
            'contents' => array (
                $arraynumber++ => array (
                    'type' => 'box',
                    'layout' => 'horizontal',
                    'contents' => array (
                        0 => array (
                            'type' => 'text',
                            'text' => $dariindo,
                            'align' => 'center',
                            'wrap' => true,
                            'gravity' => 'center',
                            'contents' => array (
                            ),
                        ),
                        1 => array (
                            'type' => 'separator',
                            'margin' => 'sm',
                            'color' => '#000000FF',
                        ),
                        2 => array (
                            'type' => 'text',
                            'text' => $bajep,
                            'align' => 'center',
                            'align' => 'center',
                            'wrap' => true,
                            'gravity' => 'center',
                            'contents' => 
                            array (
                            ),
                        ),
                    ),
                ),
            ),
        );
    }
    
    $item = array (
        'type' => 'bubble',
        'direction' => 'ltr',
        'header' => array (
            'type' => 'box',
            'layout' => 'vertical',
            'contents' => array (
                0 => array (
                    'type' => 'text',
                    'text' => $title,
                    'weight' => 'bold',
                    'align' => 'center',
                    'wrap' => true,
                    'contents' => 
                    array (
                    ),
                ),
            ),
        ),
        'body' => $itemindeks,
        'footer' => array (
            'type' => 'box',
            'layout' => 'horizontal',
            'contents' => array (
                0 => array (
                    'type' => 'button',
                    'action' => array (
                        'type' => 'message',
                        'label' => $label,
                        'text' => $text,
                    ),
                    'style' => 'primary',
                ),
            ),
        ),
    );

    return $item;

}
```

but the result not what i want, it just shows one of my data from many.
[image of the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tw9fk.png)

can anyone help me what's wrong with this code?

Thanks,

Comment: Replace `$itemindeks =` to `$itemindeks[] = `. You are over-writing your array same index again and again. Instead of that, this replacement will start assigning each data as child array to main array

Comment: Thankyou for your input, i fix that, no error on log but the bot not replying it..

Comment: but the bot not replying it- what do you mean?

Comment: Don't know what you are trying to achieve, but a bit modified function code is here : https://3v4l.org/8Z37g